# Human on an interstellar hibernation ship wakes up to deal with dangers caused by star-dwelling entities

Tags: story-identification, novel

A few colonization ships have left the Earth on different paths, with the inhabitants in hibernation. The main character of the story (I do forget what his 'title' or role is, however) is awakened throughout the journey for various issues.

Other things that happen: the sun is made to go nova by these entities that live in stars and play a (deadly) game of making the other entity's stars nova before they can escape. They live for a very long time, so their sense of time is on an exponential magnitude to that of a redwood. I think the other ship(s) got destroyed.

And for some reason I feel the main character essentially ends up being the oldest human ever.

Another part of the story I can recall is the ship gets stuck moving faster than it should due to one of these entities, and the main character has to make it stop, but they don't know why, so they're really going about it the wrong way, but, end up pissing off the star 'entity'. I wish I remembered more, but that's the reason I want to re-read the book!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Was it a physical book or an e-book?  Do you remember the cover or any art?

Answer (score 21):

I believe that is "[The world at the end of time](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?798)" by Frederick Pohl.  It concerns Viktor, a human who is a colonist to a new world where the sun is occupied by an entity known as Wan-To.  Wan-To has many siblings and children, all of whom would destroy each other if they could locate them.  They fight by blowing up stars, and Earth is destroyed as collateral damage.  As part of a distraction in his war, Wan-To accelerates Viktor's star system to relativistic speeds, which results in a human colony ship being outrun by the colony and dying in space.  Ultimately, through several bouts of cryosleep, relativistic travel via the moving star system, and some luck, Viktor winds up the oldest human being in the universe.  Wan-To generally ignores organic life is only vaguely aware that there is life in the star system he accelerated, and the humans can only ever speculate about the causes of their star systems movement and the weird super novas.

> Another part of the story I can recall is the ship gets stuck moving faster than it should due to one of these entities, and the main character has to make it stop, but they don't know why, so they're really going about it the wrong way, but, end up pissing off the star 'entity'. I wish I remembered more, but that's the reason I want to re-read the book!

That might happen, I can't remember.

> The main character of the story (I do forget what his 'title' or role is, however) is awakened throughout the journey for various issues.

Viktor may have had a title, but if I recall correctly, he wasn't anybody important.  Also, his initial journey to the colony was uneventful, and they wouldn't have woken him up anyway to help because he was a child at the start, though for most of the story he is an adult.

[Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_at_the_End_of_Time)

Comment: Baronet_Canid - THANK YOU! That's it!

Comment: @Dan It seems you've accidentally created two different accounts. If you contact support, they can merge them, and you'll be able to mark Baronet_Canid's answer as accepted.

Comment: @Dan - You can merge your accounts by following the instructions given [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @Dan - You're welcome! Could please hit accept if this answer is satisfactory?